# Evaluating a sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Evaluating a power series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243548/evaluating-a-power-series)

Can somone help me find a closed form expression for this sum given any rational value of x, and any integer p, where {x} denotates the fractional part of x.$$\sum_ {k=1}^{\infty}\frac{ \left\{p^kx \right\} }{p^k} $$ It also seems to converge to rational values.

For example if i let $p=5,x=\frac13$, the series converges to $\frac{11}{72}$